# Agenda management

Tags: packages, itemize

i have only been using latex for about half a year, and do a lot of agendas for meetings and i when i do so i but bullets in, as i am typing in bullets i remember why they are on the agenda and want to write my thouhgts under each point.

My question is, is there a package out there, that alows me to build a version with/without these comments? As i of course do not want the rest of the office to get agendas with my notes.

Thansk.

Comment: I think there is a `comment` package that might apply.

Comment: The [meetingmins](http://ctan.org/pkg/meetingmins) class has a way of hiding items if you're happy to use a class rather than a package.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot perhaps you could turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: The meetingmins class was exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`meetingmins`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/meetingmins) class allows you to have hidden items that are only displayed with the `chair` class option:

```
\documentclass[chair]{meetingmins}

\setdate{9th April 2014}
\setcommittee{Sample Committee}
\setmembers{
 \chair{Some One},
 Someone Else
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Announcements}

\begin{hiddenitems}
 \item Some hidden item.
\end{hiddenitems}

\section{Old Business}
\begin{items}
  \item \priormins
\end{items}

\section{New Business}
\begin{items}
\item Some item.
\end{items}

\nextmeeting{15th April 2014 at 15:00}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of agenda]

To switch to the agenda for everyone else, just change the `chair` class option to `agenda`:

```
\documentclass[agenda]{meetingmins}
```

This now produces:

[image: Hidden item has been suppressed]